# Changing the color of Bar based on a thresh hold value in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is a question already asked, but none of the solutions worked for me so putting up again.

1.I am trying to change the color of the bar in my D3 bar chart, based on a       certain threshold value(if the bar exceeds a particular value on the y axis say 30 in this case) How can I change the color of the bar to something else say blue.

2. I also want to draw a horizontal line at y= 30.

   Data for this is a data.tsv file

   ```
   letter  frequency   attachdate
   a   13  12-May-2016
   b   14  11-May-2016
   ```

   ```
   body {
     font: 10px sans-serif;
   }

   .axis path,
   .axis line {
     fill: none;
     stroke: #000;
     shape-rendering: crispEdges;
   }

   .bar {
     fill: orange;
   }

   .bar:hover {
     fill: orangered ;
   }

   .x.axis path {
     display: none;
   }

   .d3-tip {
     line-height: 1;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding: 12px;
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
     color: #fff;
     border-radius: 2px;
   }

   /* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
   .d3-tip:after {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     display: inline;
     font-size: 10px;
     width: 100%;
     line-height: 1;
     color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
     content: "\25BC";
     position: absolute;
     text-align: center;
   }

   /* Style northward tooltips differently */
   .d3-tip.n:after {
     margin: -1px 0 0 0;
     top: 100%;
     left: 0;
   }
   </style>

   var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 160, left: 50},
       width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
       height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

   var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

   var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
       .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

   var y = d3.scale.linear()
       .range([height, 0]);

   var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
       .scale(x)
       .orient("bottom");

   var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
       .scale(y)
       .orient("left");

   var tip = d3.tip()
     .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
     .offset([-10, 0])
     .html(function(d) {
       return "<strong>Number of days:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.frequency + "</span>"+"</b><br/>Attach date: " + d.attachdate;
     })

   var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("align","center")
       .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
       .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
     .append("g")

       .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

   svg.call(tip);

   d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
     x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
     y.domain([0, 60]);

     svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,400)")
      .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")  
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");


     svg.append("g")
         .attr("class", "y axis")
         .call(yAxis)
       .append("text")
         .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
         .attr("y", 6)
         .attr("dy", ".71em")
         .style("text-anchor", "end")
         .text("Number of days");

     svg.selectAll(".bar")
         .data(data)
       .enter().append("rect")
         .attr("class", "bar")
         .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
         .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
         .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
         .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); })
         .on('mouseover', tip.show)
         .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
   });


   svg.append("text")
           .attr("x", (width / 2))       
           .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
           .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
           .style("font-size", "18px" ) 
           .style("text-decoration", "underline")  
           .style("fill", "red")
           .text("Some heading");


   function type(d) {
     d.frequency = +d.frequency;
     return d;
   }

   </script>
   </body>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason not to do the obvious:

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", function(d) {d.frequency < threshold ? 'bar' : 'bar bar-special';})
```

etc.

Comment: So I tried this as well, it doesn't work, I am new to D3 and I am unable to find the error why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As @Stephen told you can basically make use of the class attribute to manage the color of your bars. Another approach is to use the `fill` attribute and use a function to return the desired value.

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); })
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      if (d.frequency >= 30) {
        return 'red';
      }
      return 'green';
    });
```

As for the line you want to draw you might do something like this:

```
svg.append("line")
   .attr("x1", 0)
   .attr("y1", y(30))
   .attr("x2", width)
   .attr("y2", y(30))
   .style("stroke", "#828282")
   .attr('stroke-dasharray', '2,2')
   .attr('stroke-width', '1')
```

Here is a plunker with code similar to yours: https://plnkr.co/edit/3danSMezWDsbnJZXEUTH?p=preview